# Differential equation $\Delta^k f(x)$.

Tags: binomial-theorem, finite-differences

Let $f(x)$ be a function of real variable and let $\Delta f$ be the function $\Delta f=f(x+1)-f(x)$. For $k>1$, put $\Delta^k f=\Delta(\Delta^{k-1}f)$. Then $\Delta^k f(x)$ equals:

$$\text{A) }\sum_{j=0}^{k} (-1)^{j} \binom{k}{j}f(x+j)$$
$$\text{B) }\sum_{j=0}^{k} (-1)^{j+1} \binom{k}{j}f(x+j)$$
$$\text{C) }\sum_{j=0}^{k} (-1)^{j} \binom{k}{j}f(x+k-j)$$
$$\text{D) }\sum_{j=0}^{k} (-1)^{j+1} \binom{k}{j}f(x+k-j)$$

Please tell me how to go about this question, and which topic should i study to be able to solve similar questions, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leaving $f(x)$ unknown, just start computing.

You already have $\Delta f(x)$.

Use the definition of $\Delta$ to get ${\Delta}^2f(x)$.

Next get ${\Delta}^3f(x)$.

And so on ...

Stop when all but one of the choices are eliminated.

Had there been no multiple choices offered, simply continue until a pattern becomes clear. You can then prove the validity of the discovered pattern by induction.

Comment: @The Desi Economist: My answer is "pedestrian" -- LutzL's answer is better.

Answer (score 2):

Let $S$ be the shift of the function by $1$, $(Sf)(x)=f(x+1)$, $(S^mf)(x)=f(x+m)$. Then $Δ=S-1$ and by the binomial theorem
$$
Δ^k=(S-1)^k=\sum_{j=0}^k\binom{k}{j}(-1)^j\,S^{k-j}.
$$
Now apply to $f$ at the point $x$.